# $compile not working inside callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an AngularJS directive which calls $compile inside a callback click() function. However, the contents do not seem to be getting compiled.

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.user_name = 'George';
});    

testApp.directive('testDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    template: 'Click Here',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      $(element).click(function() {
        $('#externalDiv2').html('{{user_name}}, you clicked the button.');
        $compile($('#externalDiv2')[0])(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

In the example above, #externalDiv2 still displays '{{user_name}}' instead of interpolating it with the username from the scope object.

What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/gcmLndzm/3/

Comment: `{ {` is not same as `{{` because there is a space between the braces. http://jsfiddle.net/n11nxd0x/

Comment: Yes, my question is actually about the text in #externalDiv2.

Comment: i.e because you need to do `scope.$apply();` http://jsfiddle.net/8vxw8opm/ to invoke digest cycle manually because you are doing it in a click event which is not in the context of angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.user_name = 'George';
});    

testApp.directive('testDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    template: 'Click Here',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      $('#externalDiv1').html('{{user_name}}, the directive has loaded.');
      $compile($('#externalDiv1')[0])(scope);

      $(element).click(function() {
        $('#externalDiv2').html('{{user_name}}, you clicked the button.');
        $compile($('#externalDiv2')[0])(scope);
          scope.$apply();//THIS LINE HAS BEEN ADDED
      });
    }
  };
});
```

As you are using click function, which is a part of Jquery which doesn't modify bindings,you have to call a function which can update bindings. that we do with scope.$apply OR $scope.$apply.

Comment: Why that line has been added. Please put some explanation as well in the answer.

Comment: @PSL is explanation OK now?